# Passing public Range variable to intersect

Tags: vba, object, range, intersect

I created a public Range object within my worksheet and initialized it whithin
`Worksheet_Activate()`. Afterwards I tryed to intersect the range within `Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` but I can't figure out how to do it. Maybe I am doing something totally wrong or there might be an easy way to fix it.

```
Public myRange As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()  
Set myRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D6:D8")
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Intersect(Target,myRange) Is Nothing Then
"Do Something"
Else
"Do Something Differenz"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What doesn't work with your code? Is the change code in Sheet1's module?

Comment: The whole code is in the "Sheet1" module. But it seems that I can't access the public declared variable myRange

Comment: The variable is accessed. Otherwise, you would receive an error about it. Did you look at my answer code? What do you expect from your code to behave? In order to check it, I would suggest you putting some message boxes for each case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MyRange is set only when sheet 1 is activated, so if sheet 1 is selected when the file is first opened, myRange is not set.
Rather, it would be good to put a syntax to set myRange in change_event.

```
Public myRange As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set myRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D6:D8")
    If Intersect(Target, myRange) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Nothing"
    Else
        MsgBox "not Nothing"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot trigger the sheet `Change` event without activating the page, I think...

Answer (score 0):

You must replace

```
If Intersect(Target, myRange) Is Nothing Then
```

With

```
If Not Intersect(Target, myRange) Is Nothing Then
```

If you intend to "Do Something" when the changed cell is inside `myRange`... Isn't it what you want, in fact?